# Deserializing XML with different Namespaces UWP

Tags: c#, xml, win-universal-app, deserialization

I have following XML-Data:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <e:propertyset xmlns:e="urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0">
    <e:property>
      <LastChange>
        <Event xmlns="urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/">
          <InstanceID val="0">
            <RoomVolumes val="uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=100"/>
            <Volume channel="Master" val="100"/>
            <Mute channel="Master" val="0"/>
            <RoomMutes val="uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=0"/>
          </InstanceID>
        </Event>
      </LastChange>
    </e:property>
  </e:propertyset>
```

And here are my classes:

```
[XmlRoot("propertyset", Namespace = "urn:schemas-upnp-org:event-1-0")]
public class EventPropertySet
{
    [XmlElement("property")]
    public List<EventProperty> Properties { get; set; }
}

public class EventProperty
{
    [XmlElement("LastChange")]
    public string LastChange { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SinkProtocolInfo")]
    public string SinkProtocolInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IndexerStatus")]
    public string IndexerStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SystemUpdateID")]
    public string SystemUpdateID { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I try to deserialize the XML-Data 'LastChange' is always 'null'.
When I modify the class 'EventProperty' like so:

```
public class EventProperty
{
    [XmlElement("LastChange", Namespae = "")]
    public string LastChange { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SinkProtocolInfo", Namespae = "")]
    public string SinkProtocolInfo { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IndexerStatus", Namespae = "")]
    public string IndexerStatus { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("SystemUpdateID", Namespae = "")]
    public string SystemUpdateID { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization throws an exception:
**XmlException: ReadElementContentAs() methods cannot be called on an element that has child elements. Line 1, position 103.**

Any ideas what I should do?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I found the problem. The data behind "LastChange" is normaly a parsed XML-Structure (like this:)

```
<LastChange>&lt;Event xmlns=&quot;urn:schemas-upnp-org:metadata-1-0/RCS/&quot;&gt;&lt;InstanceID val=&quot;0&quot;&gt;&lt;RoomVolumes val=&quot;uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=100&quot;/&gt;&lt;Volume channel=&quot;Master&quot; val=&quot;100&quot;/&gt;&lt;Mute channel=&quot;Master&quot; val=&quot;0&quot;/&gt;&lt;RoomMutes val=&quot;uuid:29e07ad9-224f-4160-a2bc-61d17845182a=0&quot;/&gt;&lt;/InstanceID&gt;&lt;/Event&gt;</LastChange>
```

Now when I don't do the "DeParse" with WebUtility.HtmlDecode, everythings works fine.